# warning: Attribute Unavailable: Minimum Font Scale on iOS versions prior to 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, ios-simulator

I am using xcode5 to build my app with storyboards and I started out making a deployment target as IOS 6.0, however I decided to actually change that to 5.0 deployment target.
I get this warning: "warning: Attribute Unavailable: Minimum Font Scale on iOS versions prior to 6.0"

I ran my app on the IOS 5 simulator and despite the warning, the app runs perfectly.
I've made sure that my text are not attributed but the warning still occurs, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005207/minimum-font-size-deprecated-on-ios-version-6-0

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this warning (and configure your UILabels in an iOS 5 -compatible manner,) select the offending UILabels in Interface Builder and change the value of the "Autoshrink" option to something other than "Minimum Font Scale" (the other options are "Fixed Size" and "Minimum Font Size".)